# String to BigInt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, bigint

Does anybody know how to convert a `string` to a `BigInt` without using the `BigInt()` constructor or any other libs like math etc?

So, my task is to implement arithmetic operations on strings without relying on `bigint` or arithmetic libraries. Can someone give me a hint?
Input is a valid `string` with a positive number inside, output should be `bigint`.

ChatGPT give me an answer with `BigInt()`.
I tried to use `typeOf()` operator (I don`t know am I allowed to use it).

Comment: I think you misunderstood your task. You should not rely on BigInts at all (presumably so it can run on earlier versions of ES too), so it doesn't make sense to ask how to create a BigInt in one way or another! You should build arithmetic logic that works directly on strings, perhaps. Think about how you do arithmetic on paper, you can apply the same logic here.

Comment: i am trainee so this is not related to *reality* task 
https://github.com/Citosh/SOLVD_Homework.git 
this was my answer and i received "U can't use bigInt" responce

Comment: So it's as I said - you can't use BigInt, so asking how to use BigInt in another way won't help you. You shouldn't use BigInt _at all_. Implement it yourself like you would do it on paper.

Comment: @mplungjan Since the [assignment](https://github.com/Citosh/SOLVD_Homework/tree/main/1) doesn't talk about any limits in size and just talks about arithmetic on strings, I'd assume they should support arbitrarily large numbers and the goal is to implement the right algorithms for arithmetic operations, not just converting to a number and using JS math operations. That's why I said they should think about how they'd do such operations with pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

NOTE: The numbers in the examples are exceeding [MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

```js
const addLargeNumbers = (strNum1, strNum2) => {
  // Start from the end of both strings
  let result = '';
  let carry = 0;
  let i = strNum1.length - 1;
  let j = strNum2.length - 1;

  while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || carry > 0) {
    const digit1 = i >= 0 ? parseInt(strNum1.charAt(i), 10) : 0;
    const digit2 = j >= 0 ? parseInt(strNum2.charAt(j), 10) : 0;

    const sum = digit1 + digit2 + carry;
    result = (sum % 10) + result;
    carry = Math.floor(sum / 10);

    i--;
    j--;
  }

  return result;
};
console.log(addLargeNumbers("19007199254740991","29007199254740991"))

const compareLargeNumbers = (strNum1, strNum2) => {
  strNum1 = strNum1.replace(/^0+/, '');
  strNum2 = strNum2.replace(/^0+/, '');
  
  if (strNum1.length > strNum2.length) return 1;
  if (strNum1.length < strNum2.length) return -1;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < strNum1.length; i++) {
    if (strNum1[i] > strNum2[i]) return 1;
    if (strNum1[i] < strNum2[i]) return -1;
  }
  
  return 0;
};

console.log(compareLargeNumbers("19007199254740991","19007199254740991")); // same === 0
console.log(compareLargeNumbers("19007199254740991","29007199254740991")); // str1 < str2:  -1
console.log(compareLargeNumbers("29007199254740991","19007199254740991")); // str2 < str1:  1
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but i got the task i guess
that is all about making algorithm similar to do it  by hands.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that, if my first example does not do exactly what you would do by hand!?

Comment: sorry about that 
i wanna make arithmetic operations with strings.
and after understand my task i can make it by myself. 
sorry about this misunderstanding

Comment: So answer your own question so we can see what you ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my answer approved by my mentor.

```js
String.prototype.plus = function(str) {
    let i = this.length - 1;
    let k = str.length - 1;
    let result = '';
    let carry = 0;
    
    while (i >= 0 || k >= 0 || carry != 0) {
        const dg1 = i >= 0 ? parseInt(this[i]) : 0;
        const dg2 = k >= 0 ? parseInt(str[k]) : 0;
        const sum = dg1 + dg2 + carry;
        carry = parseInt(sum / 10);
        result = (sum % 10) + result;
        i--;
        k--;
    }
    
    return result;
}

String.prototype.minus = function (str) {
    let i = this.length - 1;
    let k = str.length - 1;
    let result = '';
    let remind = 0;

    while (i >= 0 || remind != 0) {
        const dg1 = parseInt(this[i]);
        const dg2 = k >= 0 ? parseInt(str[k]) : 0;
        let sum = dg1 - dg2 - remind;
        if (sum < 0) {
            sum = (10 + dg1) - dg2 - remind
            remind = 1
        }else {
            remind = 0
        }
        result = (sum % 10) + result;
        i--;
        k--;
    }
    return result.replace(/^0*(?=[0-9])/g, '');
}

String.prototype.divide = function (str) {

    let oparatedDigits = '';
    let result = '';
    
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        oparatedDigits += this[i];
        let count = 0;

        while (parseInt(oparatedDigits) >= parseInt(str)) {
            oparatedDigits = oparatedDigits.minus(str); 
            count++;
        }
        result += count;
    }
    return result.replace(/^0*(?=[0-9])/g, '');
}

String.prototype.multiply = function (str) {
    let i = str.length - 1;
 
    let carry = 0; 
    let partialMiltiplication = 0;
    let subresult = '';
    let result = '';

    while ( i >= 0 ) {
        const dgSTR = i >= 0 ? +str[i] : 0;
        let k = this.length - 1;
        subresult = '';

        while (k >= 0){

            const dgTHIS = k >= 0 ? +this[k] : 0;

            partialMiltiplication = dgSTR*dgTHIS + carry;
            carry = parseInt(partialMiltiplication /10)
            subresult = (partialMiltiplication % 10) + subresult 
           
            k--;
        } 
  
        subresult = subresult + '0'.repeat(str.length - 1 -i)
        result = result.plus(subresult);
        
        i--;
        
    }
    return result
}
    
console.log(('23546345634563456346534565346'.plus('23546345634563456346534565346')))
console.log(('23546345634563456346534565346'.minus('23546345634563456346534565346')))
console.log('23546345634563456346534565346'.multiply('23546345634563456346534565346'))
console.log('23546345634563456346534565346'.divide('23546345634563456346534565346'))
```